# How do I create or integrate slider in my WordPress template?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have created a custom plugin for my WordPress project. That plugin required create table and insert data properly.

How do I create a slider to show the images on the WordPress template?

```
<?PHP
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "skcelebs";
    $img_tbl = $wpdb->prefix . "skimg";
    $sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name ");
    foreach ($sql as $r) {
        $sql1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $img_tbl WHERE celeb_id = '" . $r->id . "' ");
        ?>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="slider single-item">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($sql1 as $si) {
                        // print_r($si);
                        //echo $si->name;
                        ?>
                        <img src="../wp-content/uploads/celebs/<?php echo $si->name;   ?>"/>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-bottom:20px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif "> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="font-size: 2vw ;color: #7E7FB7"><?php echo $r->title; ?></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8"><?php echo $r->description; ?></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a href="<?php echo $r->fb; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;
                        <a href="<?php echo $r->tw; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;
                        <a href="<?php echo $r->insta; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;
                        <a><i class="fa fa-2x fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;

                        <a href="<?php echo $r->yt1; ?>" target="_blank">video1</a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $r->yt2; ?>" target="_blank">video2</a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $r->yt3; ?>"target="_blank">video3</a>
                    </div><br/><br/>
                    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-top: 5px"><a href="http://localhost/projects/celebs/?p=56"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">VIEW AVAILABILITY</button></a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace this line.

```
<img src="../wp-content/uploads/celebs/<?php echo $si->name;   ?>"/>
```

with this line

```
<img src="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/celebs/<?php echo $si->name;   ?>"/>
```